# Is it possible to generate model in multiple directories using Swagger codegen?

Tags: java, swagger, code-generation, swagger-codegen

I use a swagger model (using Java JAX-RS) in multiple directory (package) structure.

My target is to use the Swagger code generator in order to create the client code, having the model classes in different packages as well, using either name of the directory (package), or any other swagger specific metadata such as annotations.

I want to have my packages like

- com.schema.model.common
- com.schema.model.client
- com.schema.model.shared

As Swagger codegen input is a JSON or YAML, which was generated out of my Java classes, the package information must be either in the openAPI definition, or passed to the codegen. I found the option to specify a model package which will be the same for ALL classes, but I want them in various packages.

The topic was already posted to Swagger github issues, but was closed with recommendation to modify codegen sources:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/4634

Comment: This is something I've been looking at for a swagger related project lately.  I stopped looking when I couldn't figure out where the shared models would go, i.e. definitions referenced by different operations - how would you handle that?